# MySQL Inner Join two tables on the maximum values of the second table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I have two tables "listings" and "bids".  I have a query that will return all the listings that a particular user has bid on, where the end_date is past.  What I need to do though is limit the results even further to find only the listings where the user has bid, and is the last bidder.  Here is the query I have so far...

```
SELECT listings.end_date, listings.user_id, listings.title, listings.auc_fp, listings.id, listings.auc_image1 
FROM listings INNER JOIN bids ON listings.id = bids.listing_id 
WHERE bids.user_id=$userid 
AND listings.end_date < NOW() 
ORDER BY list_ts DESC"
```

I'm not good with subqueries and I'm assuming I'm going to need one here to find all the users bids in the "bids" table where the bid_ts (bid timestamp) is the lastest timestamp for that corresponding listing_id in the bids table.  The columns in my bids table are: listing_id, user_id, bid, bid_ts.

```
+------------+---------+------+---------------------+
| listing_id | user_id | bids | bid_ts              |
+------------+---------+------+---------------------+
|  1         | 10      | 100  | 2012-11-16 00:54:03 |
|  1         | 11      | 101  | 2012-11-16 00:54:04 |
|  2         | 10      | 33   | 2012-11-16 00:54:03 | 
|  2         | 11      | 34   | 2012-11-16 00:54:04 |
|  2         | 12      | 35   | 2012-11-16 00:54:05 |
+------------+---------+------+---------------------+
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: can you add sample records and you desired result along your question?

Comment: I edited my question to show my bids table.  What I'm trying to filter is the latest bid per user_id AND per listing_id.

Comment: Add your desired output for above data. and also specify sample data of **listing** and **bid** table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT listing_ID, user_ID, MAX(bid_ts) maxDate
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY listing_ID, user_ID
        ) b ON  a.listing_ID = b.listing_ID AND
                a.user_ID = b.user_ID AND
                a.bid_ts = b.maxDate
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8226/3)

Comment: Thank you.  I think I understand the concept a little better now.

Comment: the reason for having the subquery is that it gets separately the latest date for each listing_id for each user_id. the result of which is then join back to the original table to get the full row details `:D`